# Margins disappear when using jQuery UI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page, a snippet of which is the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/McZM8/2/embedded/result/

This is a sortable list.  However, when switching certain elements, the margin disappears.  Try switching the elements labelled "Campbell" and "Painted Post."  See how the margin between the new position of Campbell and the element labelled "Cohecton" disappears?

How can I stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to the line breaks you have between the span elements. This equates to a single whitespace character between each one.

After you drag something, it's doing away with the linebreak, therefore reducing the spacing.

See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/McZM8/3/

Either remove the spaces between each span element or switch to an unordered list.
IE may still give you an issue with linebreaks between the `<li>` tags though; I don't remember for sure.

Comment: +1 Thank you.  I'll come back in 7 minutes and accept this :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to provide an alternate solution that I found.  Changing to list items was ineffective.  The identification of the problem by simshaun was correct however.

I solved this by defining the stop function of the sortable element, and putting a newline before and after the item, like so:

```
    $('.sortable-collection').sortable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.before("\n").after("\n");
        }
    });
```

This took care of the problem, such that every element lines up and matches.